# CDI Bean-Injection failed at Hazelcast map-store class

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi, hazelcast

I'm using JBoss AS 7.1 and leveraging Contexts and Dependency Injection. There is no spring involved here.

My question is how can i inject a dependency into a hazelcast MapStore implementation? Might there be a programmatic way? Any help is appreciated.

For instance

```
public class ClientRepositoryCache implements MapStore<Integer, ClientItem> {

    @Inject
    ClientRepository repository;

    @Override
    public ClientItem load(Integer clientNumber) {
        return repository.getClientById(clientNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Hazelcast supports dependency injection using only Spring. Instead you can use `MapStoreFactory` which gives ability to create your own MapStore instance.

See a related Hazelcast group post;

> **[MapStore/MapLoader configuration](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/hazelcast/RqdIRuzG8iI/G1pF2RFI3v0J)**
>
> ...
> To integrate with Guice, for example, you can supply the name of a singleton MapStoreFactory implementation that is statically injected with enough information to implement newMapStore(String name, Properties properties) with Injector-aware logic.
>
> If you use programmatic configuration, as I do, you can avoid the static injection by passing an already-injected factory to MapStoreConfig.setFactoryImplementation.
>
> -Tim Peierls-

See also [MapStoreFactory](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapStoreFactory.html) and [MapStoreConfig](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/config/MapStoreConfig.html#setFactoryImplementation%28java.lang.Object%29) javadocs.

Comment: Any good code examples for this? Especially using CDI/WELD would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/440

This works very well! Integration with CDI done with a CDI Extension.